# HystrixCommand annotation causing ControllerLinkBuilder to break

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to apply **HATEOAS** to my spring boot application using `spring-hateoas`. This worked fine untill I wrapped my REST calls within a `HystrixCommand`:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "myFallbackMethod")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/path")
public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Data>>> getAllData() {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/someotherpath"

    ParameterizedTypeReference<Iterable<Data>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Iterable<Data>>() {};
    ResponseEntity<Iterable<Data>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, responseType);

    if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        Iterable<Data> data = response.getBody();
        Resources<Resource<Data>> resources = assembler.toResource(data);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resources, response.getHeaders(), response.getStatusCode());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getHeaders(), response.getStatusCode());
}
```

My assembler class that wraps the Data object into a Resource object now throws this error: `Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder`

If I comment the `HystrixCommand` annotation out the error is gone and everything works fine.

My assembler class just implements Springs' `ResourceAssembler<T, D>` interface and overrides the `toResource` method.

Is there any way I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I can see this as an answer, it's more like a work-around:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/path")
public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Data>>> getAllData() {
    return getAllDataImpl()
}

@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "myFallbackMethod")
public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Data>>> getAllDataImpl() {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/someotherpath"

    ParameterizedTypeReference<Iterable<Data>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Iterable<Data>>() {};
    ResponseEntity<Iterable<Data>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, responseType);

    if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        Iterable<Data> data = response.getBody();
        Resources<Resource<Data>> resources = assembler.toResource(data);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resources, response.getHeaders(), response.getStatusCode());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getHeaders(), response.getStatusCode());
}
```

I've put the content of the method that actually does the http request (and needs to be wrapped into a `HystrixCommand`) in another method. 
It works this way but it's definitely not a clean way. So if anyone knows how to solve this in a better way..